# Conversion failed while converting varchar to int

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Code behind:

```
protected void  DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string countryid = Convert.ToString(DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from states where countryID=" + countryid, con);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    con.Close();

    DropDownList4.DataSource = ds;
    DropDownList4.DataTextField = "stateName";
    DropDownList4.DataValueField = "stateID";
    DropDownList4.DataBind();

    DropDownList4.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("--select--","0"));

    if (DropDownList4.SelectedValue == "0")
    {
        DropDownList6.Items.Clear();
        DropDownList6.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--select--", "0"));
    }
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE countries 
(
    countryID varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    countryName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    localName nvarchar(100),
    webCode varchar(2),
    region varchar(50),
    continent varchar(25),
    latitude float NOT NULL,
    longitude float NOT NULL,
    surfaceArea float NOT NULL,
    population int NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (countryID),
    UNIQUE (webCode),
    UNIQUE (countryName)
);
```

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'USA' to data type int.

Comment: Little Bobby Tables alert!

Comment: countryid variable caries  'USA' value, fix it.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from states where countryID='" + countryid + "'", con);
```

Actually you missed the single quotes and your table `CountryID` is `varchar` so you must use single quotes

Comment: Still Little Bobby Tables prone.